# is it advisable to use polymorphic relations with joins?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I've created migrations and also their relationships. looks like I'm using polymorphic relations, because in one table, I could have the value of one model or i could have the value of another model. as you might guess, I have something like this

> ID Mappable_type  Mappable_id value

Mappable_type could be one or many other models. mappable_id will be appropriate id from that model. I needed this because I'm creating dynamic form builder and that's how I designed a database.

Now I need to fetch some records from 5 tables together, so I gotta use joins. the table where I have mappable_type is at the third place from those 5 joins. now What should I do also to only fetch data from these 5 joins that have specific model type that is in that morph table? I'm doing something like that for now:

```
$final = Dynamic::join('dynamic_properties_values','dynamic_properties_values.dynamic_id','=','dynamic.id')
                    ->join('dynamic_properties_mapping','dynamic_properties_mapping.id','=','dynamic_properties_values.mapping_id')
                    ->where('dynamic_properties_mapping.mappable_type','=','App\Driver')
                    ->get();
```

As you see, I have written by hand something like

> "App\Driver"

. It doesn't matter I have written it by hand or had it saved into a variable and than used it here. WHat really bothers me is that let's say when I was inserting data into these morph tables, Model got saved as "App\Driver". what if I make a mistake and when fetching with joins, I write something like App\Http\Driver? or what If I changed the location of the model itself in my code project?

What's the best practice not to make those kind of errors by the time my project reaches huge amount of users?

Comment: Do you have to use JOINs? Can you switch to Eloquent relationships?